# sqlite:constraint failed exception on inserting in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm developing database Application in wp7,when i tried to insert a record into database, it throws constraint failed exception.when I'm googling  i found that giving not null can cause the exception.so i just removed the not null from the database fields,after that i can able to insert the record successfully,but when i viewed the records, all the records filled with null values only.so i,m not able to perform any database operations.please help me to solve this problems.Here is my stracktrace

```
   at SQLiteClient.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery[T](Case toInsert)
   at Lawyers_Application.DBHelper.Insert[T](Case obj, String statement)
   at Lawyers_Application.MainPage.button1_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that stacktrace was thrown when you had a `null` constraint? There's something wrong with the data you're inserting. If a `null` constraint was initially thrown, it means you were passing `null`. Now that you've removed the constraint, the database is allowing you to insert `null` values. There's nothing wrong with the database in this context, but there seems to be something incorrect about the data you're passing.

Comment: I'm using Helper class where i can perform database operations and another class where i declare the data.for reference see here [link](http://pastebin.com/vA8mSmFb)

Comment: But is that stacktrace from when you had a null contraint?

Comment: Are you sure that the data you're entering is not null?

Comment: You need to put a breakpoint just before executing the query and checking if there any null values.

Comment: I checked All the values,all having values.see the screenshot here[link](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8115144515_7407cc447e_b.jpg )

Comment: Ok Here is the new one [link](http://picpaste.com/code-ErqhNxzL.png) for ur reference

Comment: How do you know? Does it work when you enter the data directly to the database?

Comment: sorry now only i realize that i forget to declare get and set property for the fields so what data is not stored properly,Anyway thanks for ur advice